# Installation of Microsoft Word plugin in Mendeley

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, mendeley

I recently installed the free reference manager Mendeley. When I tried to install the Microsoft Word plugin on my computer, running a 64-bit Windows 7 Professional operating system and Microsoft Word 2010, the plug-in would not show up in the ribbon under References as “Mendeley Cite-O-Matic”. What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched the Mendeley support forum and found out that I was not alone having a problem with the automatic installation of the Microsoft Word plug-in from the Tools menu. The solution that worked for me was a slight modification of one of the Mendeley agent’s suggested solutions:

1. Install MS Word plugin from the Tools menu in Mendeley Desktop.
2. Browse to C:\Users[YourUserProfile]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\Startup

   (The path might be slightly different on your machine. Remember also that the AppData folder is hidden. To make this folder visible, click Organize in the window toolbar -> Folder and search options -> View tab -> Hidden files and folders -> Show hidden files, folders, and drives)
3. Copy the file `Mendeley-1.7.1.dotm`

   (Alternatively, you may also find this file in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Mendeley Desktop\wordPlugin folder)
4. Browse to C:\Users[YourUserProfile]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\Autostart
5. Paste the file in the root of the folder.
6. Done!

The solution was to put the global template `Mendeley-1.7.1.dotm` in the Autostart folder instead of the Startup folder, which seems to be the normal folder for global templates from what I have read.

**Update for Windows 10:** In step 4 browse to the following directory instead: C:\Users[YourUserProfile]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\START to paste the file